# How to update a shopify theme

Tags: xml, shopify, e-commerce, shopify-app

Anyone can tell me how can I update shopify theme without losing customisation without using any shopify app. Is there any manual method like Wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to update a shopify theme.

1. Using Shopify App
2. Manually

Add an updated version of your theme to your online store in the following steps

1. Create a backup copy of your existing theme.
2. Visit the Shopify Theme
3. Store and log in.
4. Use the top bar search box to search for your theme.
5. On the search results page, click your theme.
6. Click Add latest theme version or Add theme.

Click [here]([https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/themes/managing-themes/updating-themes"](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/themes/managing-themes/updating-themes%22) How to update shopify theme")!

Comment: thank you so much for the information. I have checked the link and found a way to do

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to bring part of the structure to the new theme you can follow this guide:**

- Create a backup copy of your existing theme
- After uploading your updated theme, follow this instructions
- From your list of themes, choose the Actions button on the main live
  theme and then Edit code:
- Open the following file: `settings_data.json`
- Copy all the code
- Find the same file in the new Theme
- Paste the code
- Check if everything is OK.

PS: This method is recommended if you are still using Online Store 1.0

For Online Store 2.0 most part of the data is saved in the file templates, within the JSON schema.